# Not a single Software download from ubuntu software centre

Tags: apt

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to install vlc via ubuntu software centre. When I press Install, the following prompt shows up

```
**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.


vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.0.8+git20140211+r49186+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1) but 2.0.8+git20140211+r49186+4+5~ubuntu12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.10ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8-1~) but 4:0.8.10ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
     Depends: libtar0 but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva-x11-1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: libxcb-keysyms1 (>= 0.3.8) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
```

Please someone help me....

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Edit your question and add `sudo apt-get check`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install vlc type the following commands in terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
```

If there shows no error.Then type

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

For any error,report. :)

Comment: I already have tried this, there was a problem with .pk server, now i change it and everything is ok, Thanks to everyone :)